# How do you use Entity Framework Core with Identity authentication in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am following this [YouTube video by Nick Chapsas entitled "The .NET 8 Auth Changes You Must Know About!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZnu-TyaGNk). I am stuck specifically at time index `5:46` trying to run the command

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

I'm also trying to incorporate OpenApi/Swagger using the info on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/openapi?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

I installed the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations

Here is my `Program.cs` code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RpgToolsApi.Models;
using RpgToolsApi.Models.Auth;
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlite("DataSource=app.db"));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapIdentityApi<AppUser>();

app.MapGet("/", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity!.Name}!")
    .RequireAuthorization();

app.MapPost("/roll", (int Dice, int Sides) => $"Rolling {Dice}d{Sides}...")
    .WithName("RollDice")
    .WithOpenApi(generatedOperation =>
    {
        var numDiceParam = generatedOperation.Parameters[0];
        numDiceParam.Description = "The number of dice to roll.";

        var numSidesParam = generatedOperation.Parameters[1];
        numSidesParam.Description = "The number of sides on each die.";

        return generatedOperation;
    });

app.Run();
```

I also have an empty wrapper class called `AppUser` in `RpgToolsApi.Models.Auth` which inherits `IdentityUser` and another empty wrapper class called `AppDbContext` in `RpgToolsApi.Models` which inherits `IdentityDbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace RpgToolsApi.Models.Auth
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser {}
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RpgToolsApi.Models.Auth;

namespace RpgToolsApi.Models
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) {}
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

on line 2.

As a result the `AddDbContext` and `AddEntityFrameworkStores` calls raise errors on lines 11 and 15.

How can I fix the errors so I can run the migrations and create my database?

Comment: Can you share you csproj file?

Comment: Are you trageting .net 8?

Comment: Hi @Dyndrilliac, pls be sure the packages version match the target framework. Then try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Right-click on your solution in visual studio and go to >> Manage NuGet Package for Solution**

[image]

**2. Search Package Manager entityframeworkcore >> Install the package**

[image]

Similarly do for the other missing packages.